# Difference between string array with quotations and without?

Tags: swift

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["a", "b"], forKey: "xxx")

if let def = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "xxx") as? [String] {
    print(def) // ["a", "b"]
}

if let def = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "xxx") {
    print(def) // [a, b]
}
```

In the second example, when you don't explicitly cast the array to `[String]` (leaving it as `[Any]`), the print console produces an array without quotation marks which suggests they aren't strings. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out their types, you'll find that the second `def` is an array of `NSTaggedPointerString`s. `NSTaggedPointerString` is a private subclass of `NSString`, and `NSString`s print out to the console without the double quotes when inside an array.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["a", "b"], forKey: "xxx")

if let def = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "xxx") as? [String] {
    print(def) // ["a", "b"]
    print(type(of: def)) // Array<String>

    for element in def {
        print(element, "is a", type(of: element)) // a is a String
                                                  // b is a String
    }
}

if let def = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "xxx") {
    print(def) // [a, b]
    print(type(of: def)) // Array<Any>

    for element in def {
        print(element, "is a", type(of: element)) // a is a NSTaggedPointerString
                                                  // b is a NSTaggedPointerString
    }
}

print(["a", "b"] as [NSString]) // [a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are optional unwrapping/inferring the `array` to an array of strings. So it's logged as `["a", "b"]` which is the standard representation of string value in double-quotes.

In the second one, the type is not inferred so by default it's logged as an `array of Any` type values where you don't see any double-quotes.

Comment: Then `let array: [Any] = ["a", "b"]` should print `[a, b]` but it prints `["a", "b"]`.

Comment: It's because the returnType `array(forKey: )` API is `[ANY]` type. So whichever type you save it's always typecasted to `ANY` on fetch. On the other hand, `ANY` can hold almost all the datatypes. So, it's still logged with "double-quotes" in the event of an array.

Comment: Please note that `UserDefaults` is a subclass of NSObject which is not a pure swift class. Hence the `String array` you save will be of type `NSTaggedPointerString` and on the other hand `let array: [Any]` still returns the type of the Element as `String`